# Equivalent of PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, static, critical-section

Is it possible to initialise `CRITICAL_SECTION` statically, as in `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`?

In other words, is it possible in C to initialize a global `CRITICAL_SECTION` inside a library without having to mess with `DllMain` etc.?

Comment: It is not possible in plain old C without using DllMain.

Comment: You can use `InitOnceExecuteOnce` to initialize the critical section on first use. That's what `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` does under the covers.

Comment: Wow, answer from Raymond Chen. Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @raymond-chen re 'what PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER does under the covers' are you referring to some specific pthread library implementation?

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above from Raymond Chen solves the problem: "You can use InitOnceExecuteOnce to initialize the critical section on first use. That's what `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` does under the covers."

> note that this will work on Vista and above only --- @rkosegi
>
> You can do it for older versions of Windows by [writing your own `InitOnceExecuteOnce` function using `InterlockedCompareExchange`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/07/10150728.aspx). --- @RaymondChen

Comment: I guess there is no good solution for earlier version of Windows, right?

Comment: most probably no, or better say no good solution for old & new version at once.

Comment: You can do it for older versions of Windows by [writing your own `InitOnceExecuteOnce` function using `InterlockedCompareExchange`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/07/10150728.aspx).

Comment: @MartinSustrik: It is customary to enter answer as 'Community Wiki' if the answer is harvested from someone else's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply initialize in  DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and delete in  DLL_PROCESS_DETACH

```
CRITICAL_SECTION g_cs = {0};

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpReserved )  // reserved
{
    // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         // Initialize once for each new process.
         // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
            InitializeCriticalSection(&g_cs);
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
          DeleteCriticalSection(&g_cs);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}
```

**References:**

[InitializeCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[DeleteCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Won't work. As I said the solution should not require initialisation function such as DllMain or similar. The reason for that is that if the library gets linked statically, such initilisation function is not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! But you have to make sure that it's only done once per process. 
But this is typically easiest to achieve by using the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH case of the DLLMain
`switch( fdwReason )` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility in earlier versions is to instruct the linker to set a pointer to your initialization function as a user-defined global initializer.  There is some discussion of this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918180.aspx

Here is an example:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;

static void __cdecl Initialize(void) {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}
#pragma section(".CRT$XCU", read)
__declspec(allocate(".CRT$XCU"))
const void (__cdecl *pInitialize)(void) = Initialize;
```